# How to use prettyPhoto plugin with ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-plugins

I'm a total newbie in jQuery and JavaScript and need help in integrating prettyPhoto plugin into a MVC 2 application.

What I have is a view (View1) with a link "Full Screen" and a partial view rendering a galleryview plugin (PartialView1). The link "Full Screen" is calling an action method in the controller to get all the photos for a gallery. It is then returning a partial view (PartialView2) and passing the list of photos as a model. This PartialView2 is supposed to show the gallery in prettyPhoto plugin upon load.

What code do I need to put into PartialView2 to achieve this?
I've looked at prettyPhoto docs but I don't understand what I need to do. Unfortunately, I can't put this up anywhere for you guys to see. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I needed a strongly typed view (using a ViewModel) and I loop through my model to load the photos.